# Google Adsense Ads vs AdMob

Tags: android, admob, adsense, adsense-api

I am developing an android application. It's a free application, so advertisement revenue is only the earning for me.

I want to display ad on my app. I think i have two choice in Google.

1. Google Adsense Ads
2. AdMob

Which of the above is good and easy?

Answer (score 2):

**They are both one now.** Admob is a part of adsense and that is what you will use for your mobile apps whether you call it admob/adsense. Admob is primarily for mobile devices. Reporting and revenues are handled by adsense for admob.

It was before a few years that admob was a separate company and the revenues and earnings were handled separately. Not any more.

Comment: But while searching the code for  implementing, i found different code structure for both.

Answer (score 1):

Your don't have choices, on your app you will use AdMob.

Start from google official quick start tutorial:
[Admob Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)

Adsnese used to monetize and promote for websites. Since they are one company now, you can see the income and manage your admob from your adsense page as well.